# The Delphi feltxcel Excel image doesn't come out

Tags: flexcel

I'm using Delphi 6 version, but if I use the flexcel component to load Excel, the image included in Excel won't come out. Installing the same components on different pc will work well when testing. Is there anything else that needs to be set up or that is related to other components

음성듣기번역하기언어전환영어
Reinstalling Excel, Reinstalling Components, etc